# Objective C memory problem! 

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, autorelease

I have a problem in the following two code lines

```
   NSDictionary* last = [[arrHistory lastObject] autorelease];
   [arrHistory removeLastObject];
```

In the debugger I can see that, after the first code line has been executed, `last` points to a dictionary with value pairs (as it should).

The problem is the second code line. It seams to destroy the content of the dictionary. I thought the `autorelease` on line 1 would solve the problem but, it dod not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arrHistory` owns its members, you shouldn't call `release / autorelease` of its member that you don't own before you taking its ownership.

If you want to use the last object after removing, you can do it like this:

`NSDictionary* last = [[arrHistory lastObject] retain] autorelease];`

Comment: Sending an autorelease after a retain means that `last` will be released when the pool is next drained, and if the object is removed from the dictionary, last will become a garbage pointer.

Comment: @Abizern - Yes, but if the intent is to return `last` from a method whose name doesn't imply ownership, that's exactly the expected behavior. In that case, it's the caller's responsibility to `retain` the returned value if it needs to obtain ownership of it.

Comment: @Abizem Yes you are right. I just assume the last object is used only at the removing time since I saw the <code>autorelease<code> at the example code.

Comment: What's with the down votes? This is a better answer than Abizern's, which retains the object without sending it a matching release. Don't vote for the reputation, vote for the answer!

Comment: @Abizem,@Sherm, Yes my intent was to use the 'last' object only in the present method (thus, the autorelease is correct)

Answer (score 12):

What you need to do is send the object a `retain` message.

```
NSDictionary* last = [[arrHistory lastObject] retain];
[arrHistory removeLastObject];
```

Collections release objects once they are removed, which is why you need to send the `retain` message to take ownership of it.

Comment: Yes, but having taken ownership of it, you're also required to send it a `-release` or `-autorelease` when you're done with it - the latter if you're returning it from a method whose name does not imply ownership.

Comment: Yes, eventually - but the question was about stopping it from being destroyed in the next call, rather than knowing when to release it.

Comment: That's why I said "Yes, but" - adding to your answer, not disagreeing with it.